# catching input image value in controller using IE

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How do I catch the value of an image button in a controller. I have:

```
<input type="image" id="savebutton" name="savebutton" value="next" src="..." />
```

In my controller I have

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult BillingShipping(string savebutton)
    {
        ...
    }
```

This works in Firefox but not in IE. However, if I change the button into a type="submit" it works fine.

Anyone please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In IE, an `<input type="image">` includes only the coordinates when submitting the form, so the values you receive are, say, `savebutton.x=100&savebutton.y=100`. Firefox sends these values too, but also includes `savebutton=next`. IE does not.

If you just need to know that the image was clicked, the presence of the coordinates is enough. If you needed to know the value attribute, you're out of luck.

Since `savebutton.x` isn't a valid parameter name in C#, there are some handy suggestions of how to access those in your actions over here...
[[ASP.NET MVC route for serverside imagemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887648/asp-net-mvc-route-for-serverside-imagemap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887648/asp-net-mvc-route-for-serverside-imagemap)

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like in the case of multiple buttons in a form to stay away from input type="image". Hopefully css will let me make a input type="submit" with a background image that will look the same.

Answer (score 0):

An `<input type="image" />` will send an x and y coordinate of where the user clicked on the image.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution to a bit more general problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357184/input-typeimage-name-and-value-not-being-sent-by-ie-and-opera)