# HTML image input type not submitting value on Blackberry browser

Tags: blackberry, mobile-website

On the Blackberry web browser I have the following image inputs to submit a form:

```
<input type="image" name="display" value="List" src="layout_imgs/btn_list.png" alt="List" />
<input type="image" name="display" value="Map" src="layout_imgs/btn_map.png" alt="Map" />
```

It displays the image, clicking submits the form, but it doesn't submit the value for the input. Is there something I'm missing, or does this just straight up not work in Blackberry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[input type=image name and value not being sent by ie and opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357184/input-typeimage-name-and-value-not-being-sent-by-ie-and-opera)

This seems like it might be related. Multiple image types need to be handled differently.