# Image buttons not working on internet explorer

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [input type=image name and value not being sent by ie and opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357184/input-type-image-name-and-value-not-being-sent-by-ie-and-opera)

I'm really new to PHP/HTML (this is my first time working with it) and I was working on a little project to make dynamic signatures for minecraft players. The little php script works greate with google chrome, firefox, and even safari on the ipad. Yet when I test it on internet explorer it doesnt work.

I've posted my code on pastebin because there is quite alot: http://pastebin.com/nsyQ4B6q

It seems the error is occuring on line 44. There is no actual error but that is what is not working on IE.

The final output on Google Chrome is: /index.php?player=Notch&img.x=183&img.y=54&img=1Dirt.png and the signature loads correctly.

The final output on internet explorer is:index.php?player=Notch&img.x=56&img.y=51

It seems to be missions the &img=1Dirt.png and nothing happens, the page stays the same.

Comment: "I'm really new to PHP/HTML (this is my first time working with it)", "Yet when I test it on internet explorer it doesnt work" run while you can :)

Comment: Where are you seeing this error?

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't use IE, one of my minecraft servers users does and he reported this bug too me.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I know I'm new to this :( If you have any suggestions for me, do tell! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: @MattLanglois: You said `the final output is..` Where are you getting this final output? Because I did not find anything in your code which would generate  astring like `/index.php?player=Notch&img.x=183&img.y=54&img=1Dirt.png`

Comment: I was messing around a bit and it appears buttons work (as seen here http://pastebin.com/sGZwUJLk ) but it looks really bad as a button.

Comment: @Raidenace I get that in the adress bar on google chrome. Using the method get found on line 32 in my code. It gets the player from the text box and the signature from the image.

Comment: Here is an improved version of the code: http://pastebin.com/dipSLAL4. It's just a quick modernization, have a look at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org) if you need any help with HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff Thanks for that, Someone suggested I use labels I'm going to give that a shot and see if it can fix the IE problem